# Two DIVs 1 with static width, other fliud, but how to get right div to stack UNDER @ breakpoint?

Tags: html, css, position

I have two divs next to each/side by side..

The LEFT div has a FLUID width.
The RIGHT div has a static wdth.

When I resize the screen/browser... it work great! (and as intended).
However because of the way it was set up:

(Fiddle example:  http://jsfiddle.net/VHcPT/384/)

The RIGHT div in physically first in the mark-up..(and floated RIGHT).

However at say 768px breakpoint..  I need this RIGHT (static) DIV to stack UNDER the LEFT div..  how can I achieve this?

If I physically have the RIGHT div AFTER the LEFT div in the markup.. it would stack as expected.. but I need to have it FIRST so the fluid/static behavior in place works as it should.

So to re-cap, its NOT about getting the two divs next to each other one fluid, one static.. its how to handle that at a responsive/breakpoint.. and get the static (RIGHT) div to stack UNDER the fluid (LEFT) div

Using the fiddle example.. the RED DIV would go UNDER (stack) the GREEN lines/div.. (the green would then be full width).. at a certain breakpoint.

and because code is required now:

HTML:

```
<div id="contentcontainer">
    <div class="rightcontainer">mm</div>
    <div class="leftcontainer">
        <div class="item_1">
            some text
        </div>
        <div class="item_2">
            some text
        </div>        
    </div>        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#directorycontainer {
    padding:10px 10px;
    display:table;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: normal;
}


.directory {
    background: green;
    margin-right: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.mapcontainer {
    background: red;   
    display:table; 
    width:240px;
    height:480px;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.providercontainer{
    background-color: #f7f9fb;
    border: 1px solid #e1dacd;
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 0.625em;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Is this NOT possible then?
(really?)

Answer (score 0):

OK well looks like this works and should be an acceptable answer/solution:

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VHcPT/389/

HTML/Markup:

```
<div id="contentcontainer">
    <div class="leftcontainer">
        <div class="item_1">
            some text
        </div>
        <div class="item_1">
            some text
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="rightcontainer">mm</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

#contentcontainer {
    padding:10px 10px;
    display:table;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: normal;
}


.leftcontainer {
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    float:left;
    width:calc(100% - 240px);
}

.rightcontainer {
    background: red;   
    display:table; 
    width:240px;
    height:480px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item_1{
    background-color: #f7f9fb;
    border: 1px solid #e1dacd;
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 0.625em;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

works with whatever breakpoints you set and the elements will stack correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you may like my FLEXBOX alternative to you problem. It may take a bit of practice, but it will eventually give you much more control.

[The FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/renevanderlende/q04ampco/)

Below the basic CSS structure, no other 'display', 'position' or 'overflow' needed. With this structure you can mix-match any number of fixed and/or fluid columns.

```
.flex--box   { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap }
.flex--fluid { flex: 1 1 auto }
.flex--fixed { flex: 0 0 auto; min-width: 240px }

/* MOBILE MQ */
@media all and (max-width: 360px) {
    .flex--fluid, .flex--fixed {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have problem with it.

And of course, do give credit if you think it is worth it.
( BTW: I changed the colors to something less retina intensive &D )

Comment: About the DUPE, please don't meddle about 'typical SO community', some answers take time, spare time, that is. Just be patient, you will get read...

Comment: it said it was closed because there was an answer... (but there wasnt)